# Unable to use SQLite in react native. my react native version is 0.64.3

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I am new in react native environment, and not able to use SQLite in react native. my react native version is 0.64.3. I am getting the error .I have added the package:
npm install react-native-sqlite-storage --save

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModules["SQLite"][method]')

please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i having the same issue. were you able to resolve it?